# Convert an Mac OS X binary formatted plist to readable format in C#

Tags: c#, .net, macos, binary, plist

Does anyone know if/how I can convert a binary formatted Mac OS X plist file to a plain XML string in C#?

I know there are some plist editors for Windows available that says they support binary formatted plist files, but I need to do this inline in my own application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realize this is super old, but I'm posting my solution for posterity.

I couldn't find anything usable sort of launching an external process when I embarked on binary plist serialization a few weeks ago, so I had to roll my own.

For others looking for C#/.NET binary plist serialization, you can find my implementation at https://github.com/ChadBurggraf/plists-cs.

Hopefully this helps some folks out.

Comment: Sweet! Although it's quite some time since I worked on this, I'll take a look at adding this instead of launching an external process as I'm currently doing

Comment: Works well for me too. Nice job.

Answer (score 1):

a quick google reveals [plutil.pl](http://scw.us/iPhone/plutil/), but that will only work if perl is installed (which I'm fairly certain is not the default in windows)

Comment: I found that one too, but I don't want to add perl as yet another requirement to my application. The best would be to be able to use the encodings in the framework, but I start to doubt that they are able to convert this format.

Comment: I found an executable version of this utility. In my code, I write the binary plist to a file, use plutil.exe to convert it to plain XML and then read in the result file.

Comment: @Geir-ToreLindsve - Can you please post an answer and link to where/ how you found the `plutil.exe` - Please share.

Comment: @AlexS Late reply, but I have no idea where I found it and haven't worked on this application for a few years

Comment: @Geir-ToreLindsve - If you have a copy of the .pl and .exe, can you please upload and share it, via GitHub or online location, so that we can make use of this answer. Also, can you update/ detail it out a bit. Thanks. Merci Buco.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried any of the solutions below, and I know you were looking for C# but...

This page has a binary plist parser implemented in java:
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Swing/JIDE-Common/com/jidesoft/plaf/aqua/BinaryPListParser.java.htm

The Java Quaqua project (https://quaqua.dev.java.net/) uses a binary plist java parser. You can see the java doc here http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/javadoc/ch/randelshofer/quaqua/util/BinaryPListParser.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe it can be ported to C#

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the conversion in code on the OS X side, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264440/converting-plist-to-binary-plist) previous SO question has your answer. Alternatively, you can use the [plutil](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/DARWIN/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html) command line utility on OS X to convert between binary and XML property lists.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to read a binary formatted plist at runtime in my .NET application. The reason is that CoreData stores metadata in this format and I have a cross platform application that needs to read the same data file as the mac version.

We might have to pull it off by duplicating the metadata in a separate table though, as I have yet to find a reliable way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

Project Wonder has the open sourced version of Apple's plist parser from WebObjects that supports binary plists: http://wonder.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wonder/branches/Wonder_5_0_0_WebObjects_5_4_Branch/Wonder/Frameworks/Core/ERExtensions/Sources/er/extensions/foundation/ERXPropertyListSerialization.java?revision=11806&content-type=text%2Fplain